# How to turn on Cocos2D CCLOG Debug mode?

Tags: ios, debugging, cocos2d-iphone, logging

Around the web I see people posting things like this:

```
2012-03-12 10:26:32.495 squirrels[330:707] cocos2d: OS version: 5.1 (0x05010000)
2012-03-12 10:26:32.498 squirrels[330:707] cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Imagination Technologies
2012-03-12 10:26:32.501 squirrels[330:707] cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: PowerVR SGX 543
2012-03-12 10:26:32.503 squirrels[330:707] cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES 2.0 IMGSGX543-63.24
2012-03-12 10:26:32.505 squirrels[330:707] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
2012-03-12 10:26:32.507 squirrels[330:707] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
2012-03-12 10:26:32.508 squirrels[330:707] cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
2012-03-12 10:26:32.510 squirrels[330:707] cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
2012-03-12 10:26:32.511 squirrels[330:707] cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
2012-03-12 10:26:32.513 squirrels[330:707] cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
2012-03-12 10:26:32.515 squirrels[330:707] cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
2012-03-12 10:26:32.516 squirrels[330:707] cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
2012-03-12 10:26:32.519 squirrels[330:707] cocos2d: cocos2d v2.0.0-beta2
2012-03-12 10:26:32.522 squirrels[330:707] cocos2d: Using Director Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
```

However I do not get logs like this when I run my app in debug mode. Is there a way to turn this on using Cocos2D 2.0? And if so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: I found out the answer. All you have to do is put: #define COCOS2D_DEBUG 1 into your .pch file and thats it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this statement to your PCH file:

`#define COCOS2D_DEBUG 1`

That should set the preference to turn it on.

Comment: Format specifiers: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_use_CCLOG in addition, do a search for "CCLOG" in the samples to see more format specifier usage

Comment: Note: COCOS2D_DEBUG is set in the Xcode build settings, so check there first.

Answer (score 0):

to enable cocos debug , i add those lines in my Application.mk

```
 APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 -std=c++11 -fsigned-char
 APP_OPTIM := debug
```