# CCAssert() and CCLOG() don't work in cocos2dx classes

Tags: xcode, debugging, cocos2d-x

I have a problem with `COCOS2D_DEBUG`. `CCAssert()` and `CCLOG()` is enabled in the classes I created but not inside any cocos2dx classes. I see my logs in debug console but logs of cocos2dx is not displaying even if I traced them using step-in, step-out, etc.

I added new scheme to my project so I can switch provisioning profile easily. I added `COCOS2D_DEBUG = 1` on that scheme in `Preprocessor Macros` in `Build Settings`. I have it all setup and it is working except for the problem in `CCAssert()` and `CCLOG()`.

I have no idea why they are not working. I need them specially CCAssert() to prevent any wrong code that I am doing. I need to enable them since I'm in a team project.

I am using the new scheme that I created. I notice in `cocos2dx.xcodeproj` > `Build Settings` > `Preprocessor Macros`, there are only `Debug` and `Release`. Do I need to add also my scheme in `cocos2dx.xcodeproj`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn on Cocos2D CCLOG Debug mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959053/how-to-turn-on-cocos2d-cclog-debug-mode)

Comment: Also see [debug and logging](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/2365) on the community forums.

Comment: Can it be fixed without adding `#define COCOS2D_DEBUG = 1` in `.pch` file? I guess I need to manually edit that file before archiving so the debug codes is not included in the release version of the product.

Comment: It looks like that's the route. Both the previous SO question and the forum post recommend it. You could guard it with `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` in the precompiled header. See [NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445222/ns-block-assertions-in-objective-c).

Comment: I am using `cocos2dx` which is in c++. And also in `Debug` scheme, logs and assertion inside cocos2dx classes works. When I switch to my scheme, they don't work. I'm currently looking for the difference of `Debug` and my scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Try using CClog() instead of CCLOG()

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have faced this issue before.You need to use CCLog instead of CCLOG